# Android java split string via special character fails

Tags: java, android

I would like to attach a platform parameter to a url with `?` if the url has no query string and using `&` if url has a query string

SO i have added the following

```
 String api_url;
 //costructor next to assign apiurl value

 //method to extract url and process request
 processData(){
    String apiUrl = "";
    String[] urlParams = this.api_url.split("\\?");
    if (urlParams.length > 0){
        apiUrl = this.api_url+"&platform="+tokenService.getToken(AppDetailsHelpers.AppSettingsKeys.PLATFORM);
    }else {
        apiUrl = this.api_url+"?platform="+tokenService.getToken(AppDetailsHelpers.AppSettingsKeys.PLATFORM);
    }
}
```

The above always evaluates the `urlParams` to a an array even when a url doesnt contain the `?`

Example for a url

```
http://test.com
```

is resolved with the above code as

```
http://test.com&platform=12
```

But i expected it to be as `http://test.com?platform=12`

I have tried adding

```
String[] urlParams = this.api_url.split("?");
```

But it throws an error of `Dangling metacharacter`. What am i missing out on this. Why does this fail.

Comment: Why do you expect `split` to return nothing when the regex didn't match? Have you verified your claim? Also, why don't use just use `contains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour for `String#split`. Running `"http://test.com".split("\\?")` returns an array with one element, `"http://test.com"`. So, just update your condition to `if(uriParams.length > 1)`.

You could also consider parsing your String to a Uri, as you may not need this check and could possibly instead use:

```
Uri.parse(api_url)
    .buildUpon()
    .appendQuery("platform", tokenService.getToken(AppSettingsKeys.PLATFORM))
    .build().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks I had to add  .buildUpon() on Uri.parse(api_url) otherwise .appendQuery shows an error. SO its Uri.parse(this.api_url)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("platform", tokenService.getToken(AppDetailsHelpers.AppSettingsKeys.PLATFORM))
                .build().toString()

Comment: Sorry, I was working from memory - I've updated my answer